# Unlocking private SSH key (with Cygwin/X11) when there is no local shell involved?

Tags: ssh, cygwin, xorg, ssh-agent

I have installed Cygwin/X11, including `openssh`. I have set up a public / private key pair. I have installed the public key in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` of RemoteHost.

I have configured Cygwin/X11 (via `~/.XWinrc`) to provide a menu item which opens a RemoteHost shell in a local terminal:

```
menu root {
    RemoteShell    exec    "/bin/xterm.exe -e /usr/bin/ssh -Yl <user> RemoteHost"
}

RootMenu root
```

I want to be queried for the passphrase of my private key when this menu item is selected the first time. I do **not** want to be queried on subsequent calls.

As there is no local shell involved, i.e. I cannot do anything (like setting up `ssh_agent` or `keychain`) in `~/.bash_profile`, I am a bit at a loss here. There is also no shell in which to **enter** the keyphrase.

**How do I unlock my private SSH key when there is no local shell involved?**

Answer (score 1):

- You can start `ssh-agent` in subsequent shell and to the new one export the environment variable (for example from a file created in the first one)

  ```
  ssh-agent > ~/.ssh_agent_env
  source ~/.ssh_agent_env
  ```
- You can get asked for a passphrase using a GUI prompt, which is provided to `ssh` by the environment variable `SSH_ASKPASS`. In Linux, usually `gnome-askpass` or similar. There will be something similar in cygwin too.
- There is `AddKeysToAgent` option, which will add the newly used keys to the running `ssh-agent` to achieve what you need.

Both these would need some coding/checks before calling the final `ssh`, for example a bash script you can call in the `RemoteShell exex /path/to/my/script.sh`, for example:

```
#!/bin/bash
ps aux | grep ssh-agent | grep -v grep
if [ "$?" = "1" ]; then
  # start a new agent (in a background) and store its environent
  ssh-agent > ~/.ssh_agent_env
end
# load existing ssh-agent connection
source ~/.ssh_agent_env

/bin/xterm.exe -e /usr/bin/ssh -oAddKeysToAgent=yes -Yl <user> RemoteHost
# or do whatever magic you want
```

Comment: Can you believe the thought of a local wrapper script didn't even occur to me? 8-\